# Best practice for selecting birth year

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

Background: I've want my users to select their birth year from a list of birth years.

I'm currently using a spinner with an item resource in XML that creates a long-scrolling drop-down list. I've read posts on using DatePicker but it would require some major modifications that make is somewhat unstable from platform to platform. So my question is:

How best to represent a selectable list of years in a form?

Comment: why not allow the user to type in the year his/herself in a textbox? you can do the validation on your end. Is there a reason you're not considering this route?

Comment: I wanted to avoid the handlers out of concern for delaying the user. I think canned options are a better way to go for the mobile platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is much of best practice available here. What you choose will depend on the feel of your application and how well the method integrates with it.

That said, a simple `EditText` is likely best - nothing clever required. Consider also setting `android:digits="1234567890"` on it. Doing so will also display the comfortable numeric keyboard.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you. I'm trying to limit users ability to input bad data and your idea might do the trick if I use a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I'm familiar with the andriod user interface but why does it have to be mutually exclusive to either selecting or typing in a year? Cannot you have a textbox with a drop down button next to it to select a year?

For me personally, I'd consider a date picker to be a little extreme unless you are wanting their full DOB in which case you need to be *really* careful how you do it due to the large variations on date representations throughout the world; in that situation then a date picker would possibly be the most suitable option.

*Edit:* Just something to note, if you do choose a drop down list, make sure by default you select a suitable year rather than the most recent. You know your users best but it is unlikely that you'll get a 10 year old using your app, and showing 10 items (which would automatically be skipped for 99.99% of the users) on a drop down listbox can be quite a bit of screen real estate on a small device.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't seen a widget of a textbox with a dropdown list. I'll look for that.